# Manual pages for C programming on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, manpage

I want a manual for C programming language to install it on Ubuntu 11.10 , I want to execute `man function` and be able to view the documentation as I do on system calls and functions.

Which package should I install ?

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo apt-get install manpages-dev manpages-posix-dev glibc-doc
```